# Upgrading an older tablet (from 4.4)

Tags: updates

Is this a question which has a definitive (and generic) answer? I don't know, which is why I ask.

If I buy an older tablet on Ebay, which is running Android 4.4, can I upgrade it to 5 or even 6?

Is there a single answer, or is it model by model specific?

If I decide to try it anyway, I would like to hope that I can't brick it so badly that I couldn't reinstall 4.4 - can anyone confirm or deny that?

And what sort of things do I need to look out for? I imagine that older processors are likely to run newer operating systems more slowly, so performance could be an issue. But, is there anything else that I need to be aware of?

I do hope that this question doesn't get closed as being too vague, because I believe that there is/are a precise answer(s) could be very helpful to a lot of people.

Comment: Whether you *can* depends on the make of tablet.  A bigger question is whether you *should*.  Given that 5 runs more slowly than 4 on the same hardware, why run the risk?

Comment: 1) to get the features of the new o/s 2) to use apps which only run n the new o/s 3) it may be in a few years time that 4 won't still be officially supported, but 5 or 6 will